# UIColor clearColor

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uicolor

The documentation says the clearColor's grayscale and alpha = 0.  What does that actually mean?  Is it just a color to match whatever the background is?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

clearColor is exactly what it says, its clear, so whatever the color is of the view behind the clearColor view, will show through. Think of it as being like clear glass, it is see through e.g. has an alpha value of 0 (zero).

So, say your window background is Red and the background of the view you place on on top of it is clearColor then you will see Red...

Comment: No it is not just what it says. It is the clear color corresponding to black, which makes a big difference. Try creating a gradient between white and clearColor and you will see some gray - while you expect something just white.

Comment: Also, FWIW, background.color = nil IS NOT the same as UIColor.clear.

Comment: @AMC08 what is the difference between `nil` and `.clear`?

Answer (score 18):

Not sure if you wanted the individual definitions. Yes, the `[UIColor clearColor]` is transparent. However specific to "The documentation says the clearColor's grayscale and alpha = 0. What does that actually mean?"

a) A grayscale of 0 is equal to the color black.

b) alpha is equal to opacity where 1 is solid and 0 is transparent.

Therefore the documentation is saying that `clearColor` is the color black with a completely transparent opacity. (which makes what color it is immaterial)

Basically whatever color/image is behind it will shine through with 100% clarity.

Comment: why is the "grayscale" bit relevant?

Comment: @Novellizator, technically the "grayscale" is not with regard to the use of clearcColor. I was just referencing what the Apple documentation details because the original question asks, "...the clearColor's grayscale and alpha = 0. What does that actually mean?"

Answer (score 14):

It means it's transparent, so yeah, the backgrounds color.

FYI: It will probably be the color you use the most. For instance if you put a label on an image you need the label's background to be transparent.

```
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```